# Error inflating class after migration to androidx

Tags: android, androidx

I made a migration to Androidx but after the migration, I'm getting the following error:

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

I studied all the resources and migrated to Androidx, but I still have a lot of problems.
Can someone help me?
I will post the sections of the code below.

--------- beginning of crash ---------

```
2019-01-23 09:47:34.171 17578-17578/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ir.bijac.com.bijac, PID: 17578
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.bijac.com.bijac/ir.bijac.com.bijac.TestActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:964)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at ir.bijac.com.bijac.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:43)
        at ir.bijac.com.bijac.TestActivity.onCreate(TestActivity.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/coreui/R$attr;
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:202)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:964) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at ir.bijac.com.bijac.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:43) 
        at ir.bijac.com.bijac.TestActivity.onCreate(TestActivity.java:22) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
2019-01-23 09:47:34.171 17578-17578/? E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.coreui.R$attr" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ir.bijac.com.bijac-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.bijac.com.bijac-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.bijac.com.bijac-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.bijac.com.bijac-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.bijac.com.bijac-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.bijac.com.bijac-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.bijac.com.bijac-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.bijac.com.bijac-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.bijac.com.bijac-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.bijac.com.bijac-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.bijac.com.bijac-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ir.bijac.com.bijac-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ir.bijac.com.bijac-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 27 more
```

build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.bijac.com.bijac"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.1.1'
    configurations.all { resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0' }
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    implementation "cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.2"
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.10'
    implementation 'com.androidadvance:topsnackbar:1.1.1'
    implementation 'co.ronash.android:pushe-base:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

}
```

--------- activity_main.xml ---------

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    >

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: just go to refactor->migrate to androidx this will check if there is any resource which is unhandled if not then just delete your .idea folder in your root project and start over it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I tested `refactor->migrate to androidx`  And I made the changes.

Comment: have u tried deleting your .idea folder to delete old cache.

Comment: its not work for me.

Answer (score 9):

You are likely to have a reference to `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` in some of your xml layout files.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> or go to `Edit/Find/Find in Path` and just search for `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` and replace it with `androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout`.

You may use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or `Edit/Find/Replace in Path` instead to replace all matches at once.

Answer (score 6):

in XML file, replace

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.RecyclerView
```

with:

```
androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like app is trying to inflate `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`  from support library instead of androidx library. Try doing following things and check if it works.

- Do `clean and build` your app.
- Try `Invalidate Cache and Restart`.

Also make sure you are not using coordinator layout from support library anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I tested both methods.
its not work for me.

Comment: make sure you have not used coordinatorlayout from support library in any other xml.

Comment: I sure any other xml not used coordinatorlayout from support library

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in your activities and fragments there is no reference to the old support libraries in the imports section.Make sure all layouts are not using the ols support widgets too.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines in gradle.properties file to automatically migrate existing project to Androix.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

more info here -> https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

this will automatically solve ur problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer butI have already added these two lines in gradle.properties file

Comment: @hassanabbasi, have u tried 1. invalidate cache and restart 2. clean and rebuild project?

Answer (score 0):

Simply Just go to XML file (in `res/layout) and replace

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.RecyclerView
```

with:

```
androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace all `android.support.design` classes with new classes of *AndroidX*. Here are the links with the correspondences between old and new classes:

- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings
- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings

Fore more you can read the guide how to migrate to *AndroidX*:

- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 0):

Edit --> Find --> Find in Path
**Replace all** of following

- `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`
  -->   `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`
- `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`
  -->   `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`
- `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`
  -->   `androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView`
- `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`
  -->   `androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager`
- `androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout`
  -->   `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`
- `androidx.core.view.ViewPager`
  -->   `androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager`
- `androidx.core.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout`
  -->   `androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout`
- `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`
  -->   `com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout`
- `android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout`
  -->   `com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout`
- `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`
  -->   `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`